# Angular velocity of point on rigid body

Tags: classical-mechanics, rigid-body-dynamics

a while back I asked this question and I still did not fully understand.

Suppose we have a rigid object rotating about some central point with a given linear and angular velocity, how do we then compute the angular and linear velocity of another point on the rigid body?

Comment: The angular velocity of a rigid body is a free vector, which means it is the same for all points on the rigid body. The same applies to angular acceleration.

Answer (score 0):

As Mr. Hammen points out, the angular velocities are all the same.  With an axis of rotation, the tangential velocity, v = rω, for each point.